# Android Facebook SSO Login failed

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I'm trying to use Facebook SSO on my Android app.
I got the hash key with keytool and saved it on Facebook app setting for developers. then, succeeded to SSO login.

However, I deleted my app on Facebook app setting for users. then, failed to SSO login.
Below is Logcat info.

The issue is that do not work after deleting the app on user app setting.
Thanks in advance.

```
03-08 03:46:49.074: D/Facebook-authorize(23658): Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "pU3yrmSnaG22uvh1x5cizKxXwCI" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that key in the logs to your list of hash keys on your Facebook Developer app account.

Comment: This problem was solved itself 12 hours after. It may take lots of times(over 12 hours) to save the key hash on facebook settings. It may be a bug on android facebook app.(https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/275345489193008?browse=search_4f1e0b2ccafcd9675510722)

Answer (score 0):

change your hash key in Facebook Apps with following changes

[image]